# Windows Store App how to continuously read from a TCP socket and update the UI when "\n" is received

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, windows-store-apps, datareader

I am working with [this](http://donatas.xyz/streamsocket-tcpip-client.html) code in order to comunicate with another program through TCP which acts as a server. My app is also a Windows Store App and I just added the 3 methods to my code. The server is not made by me, I can't modify it in any way. Connection and sending messages works fine. After I give a specific command to the server, it sends back a continuous stream composed of strings that end in "\r\n" in order to see when a message ends, something like this: `"string1\r\nstring2\r\n"` and so on, as long as there is a connection with it. Note that sending the command works because I get a visual response from the server.

I can not find a way to display the individual strings in my app's UI, I think my problem lies in the `read()` method, because the stream never "consumes":

```
public async Task<String> read() 
    {
        DataReader reader;
        StringBuilder strBuilder;

        using (reader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream))
        {
            strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            // Set the DataReader to only wait for available data (so that we don't have to know the data size)
            reader.InputStreamOptions = Windows.Storage.Streams.InputStreamOptions.Partial;
            // The encoding and byte order need to match the settings of the writer we previously used.
            reader.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
            reader.ByteOrder = Windows.Storage.Streams.ByteOrder.LittleEndian;

            // Send the contents of the writer to the backing stream. 
            // Get the size of the buffer that has not been read.
            await reader.LoadAsync(256);

            // Keep reading until we consume the complete stream.
            while (reader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0)
            {
                strBuilder.Append(reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength));
                await reader.LoadAsync(256);
            }

            reader.DetachStream();
            return strBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
```

I have an event on a button that calls `send()` having a parameter the string command I wish to send. At first, I simply tried `textBox.Text = await read();` after calling the `send()` method, nothing appeared in the `textBox`. Next, I tried making the `read()` method to not return anything and putting `textBox.Text = strBuilder.ToString();` in different places inside `read()`. Finally, I discovered if I put it inside `while (reader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0)` after `strBuilder.Append(reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength));` the `textBox` gets updated, although I'm not sure if the strings really appear correctly, but my UI becomes unresponsive, probably because it gets stuck in the `while` loop. I searched the internet for multiple examples, including how to do it in a separate thread, unfortunately my experience is entry-level and this is the best I could do, I don't know how to adapt the code any further. I hope I have been explicit enough. Also, I don't mind if you show me a different, better way of updating the UI